# subprocess.run pipe stdout/stderr empty

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I'm doing

```
result = subprocess.run(
    command.split(),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    check=True,
    text=True
)
```

where `command` = python3 'file_path' OR ruby 'file_path' etc
I need to get all out

file.py

> print('123') # -> out is '123'
>
> prjasnt('123') # -> out NameError: name 'prjasnt' is not defined

But result.stdout is always empty (for ruby also)

What am i do wrong ?

Using Python3.8, Mac Os, Ubuntu18

UPD: My full code

```
import functools
import os
from abc import abstractmethod

import pebble
import subprocess
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass


def run_app(command):
    return subprocess.run(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, check=True, text=True)

class IAppExecutor:
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, run_command: str, app_file_path: str, timeout: int = 15):
        raise NotImplementedError


@dataclass
class AppExecutor(IAppExecutor):
    _process_pool = pebble.ProcessPool()

    def run(self, run_command: str, app_file_path: str, timeout: int = 15):
        return self._process_pool.schedule(functools.partial(run_app, run_command.format(app_file_path)))
```

That is who I use it

```
async def execute_program(message: RunAppMessage, run_app_police=RunAppPolice(), executor=AppExecutor()):
    run_command = run_app_police.get_command(message.lang, message.lang_version)
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('x+') as tmp:
        tmp.write(message.code)
        result = await asyncio.wrap_future(executor.run(run_command, tmp.name, timeout=message.timeout))
    return Response(status_code=200, content=f'{result.stdout}')
```

Comment: What does the variable `command` contain, when `split()` is called on it?

Comment: Can you please show your full code? Especially how you read from `result.stdout` and how you wait for `result` to complete.

Comment: @DanielJunglas Added UPD in question

Comment: @RichardNeumann it contains ["python3", "path_to_file"] or ["ruby", "path_to_file"]

Comment: `command.split()` is a bad idea. It'll fail very badly when your filenames contain spaces, or quoted arguments, etc etc. It's much safer to write your argument list _as a list_ -- that way you're explicitly specifying exactly what will be executed.

Comment: BTW, updates are best written into the main text; we don't expect update markers or edit markers here -- you should be writing your question for people who are seeing it for the first time, as the goal here is to build a long-lived knowledgebase. Someone who already saw your question earlier and wants to know what changed can get that by checking the edit history.